# Object recognition from photo in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, artificial-intelligence, object-recognition

I am currently looking to add a functionality where the user takes a photo (which has already been implemented) and then have it analyzed where either the landscape or the object is identified.

I came across Microsoft Cognitive Services (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/using-object-detection-from-inside-your-xamarin-app/) that works fine!

The only issue now that i've implemented this library is that i am limited in the way that i have to manually write in the things i want identified in the picture.

My question now is if there is a SDK or library out there that does what im looking for? So lets say the user takes a photo of an apple, beer or a chocolate bar then i want those tags returned to me after the photo has been analyzed.

Comment: It's not easy, I can give you the solution but you need research. First use Tensorflow Object Detection API to train the your model that you use to identify object, then use Xamarin.Tensorflow.Lite to use that model. That's it.

Comment: @PhatHuynh Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Is there any example out there on how to accomplish this?